# html2canvas issue with icons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html2canvas

Hello I am trying to print a div of list of notes with some icons with the help of html2canvas.[image]

see above is my input image. [image]

but I am getting this output. Please help me if any one

```css
    .icon-circle:before {
      content: "\e941";
    }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 85px; padding:5px 0;"> 
  <i class="icon-circle" style="color:"blue">
     <span style="color: white;font-size: 18px;position: absolute; top: 22px;left: 13px;"> T
     </span>
   </i>
</div>
```

have any solution

Comment: I think your problem is the position absolute on the icon. Why position absolute? Try relative positioning to avoid calculation problems on conversion.

Comment: Thanks @MarcosPérezGude
yes this is because of position, but how can I get that text above that icon without giving it position I tried absolute also but its giving me same result as above.

Comment: Well its issue will html2canvas 0.5.0-alpha1. I have reported it on github, you can see my fiddles and other details about it on github https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1001

Comment: Give relatives position to the icons and relative spans into the icons. Easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally in the new version 1.1 of html2canvas I got the solution **[#1001](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1001)**.

Here is the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j09qd4xm/7/)**

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        width:320,
        height:220
    }).then(function (canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   });
}
```